# How to set flow types for callbacks in event listeners

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have an application with event listeners and pubsub.

Each of the events would have a completely different type of payload, and flow would yell at me if I don't check if the inputs are of valid types in the callbacks.

```
const handleAuctionEnd = (auctionData: {auctionResult: string}) => {
const {auctionResult} = auctionData;
if (!auctionResult) return;
//doSomethingCool
}
const handleRequestEnd = (requestData: {requestStatus: number}) => {
const {requestStatus} = requestData;
if (requestStatus === undefined) return
//doSomethingCooler
}
myLibrary.onEvent(EVENTS.AUCTION, handleAuctionEnd);
myLibrary.onEvent(EVENTS.REQUEST, handleRequestEnd);
```

This was okay for small numbers of event types. But as the number grows, the type of flow errors become complex and becomes unmaintainable.

Is there a way to properly type flow types in event listener callbacks?

Comment: Do you have separate type definitions for each event? I would probably name each payload separately then refer to the event types directly in the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this to make the code a bit cleaner. According to Flow's documentation,

> if we create a union type of both object types, Flow will be able to know which object we’re using based on the success property.

```
type AuctionResult = { auctionResult: string};
type RequestStatus = { requestStatus: number};

type CallbackParam = AuctionResult | RequestStatus
```

You can define the param type as `CallbackParam`. You might still have to define multiple types but it is a bit more organized than defining them inline.

```
const handleAuctionEnd = (auctionData: Callback) => {...}
```

Reference https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions